# Why does this LINQ join query work, but this other one doesn't?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, exception

I've written two LINQ queries using the join method.  Essentially, if I switch the order of the objects to be joined, the query no longer works and throws the error:

"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Domain.Entities.UsersSitesRole'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

```
        var foo2 = //works
            from p in privilegesForUser
            join c in repository.Child on p.SiteId equals c.Child_SiteID
            select new { ChildID = c.Child_ChildID, name = c.Child_FirstName, site = c.Child_SiteID, p.PrivilegeLevel };

        var foo3 = //throws exception
            from c in repository.Child
            join p in privilegesForUser on c.Child_SiteID equals p.SiteId
            select new { ChildID = c.Child_ChildID, name = c.Child_FirstName, site = c.Child_SiteID, p.PrivilegeLevel };
```

The object `privilegesForUser` is a List of entities derived from my Entity Framework context (UsersSiteRole), and `repository.Child` is an `IQueryable<Child>` from my EF context as well.

Comment: Please also show the Exception thats being thrown.

Comment: @Jethro: Read the question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the way EF parses the expression tree it gets in the extension methods.

There are many cases, where a query is logically correct and executes just fine on `IEnumerable` (Linq to Objects) but fails in Linq to Entities. Basicly, it's pretty much impossible to compile just any logical expression tree into proper SQL statements (SQL is not ideal and far from object oriented world) and this is the case where EF gives up. In time, you get used to understanding what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I just came across this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513866.aspx) which seems to indicate I shouldn't even be attempting what I'm doing (joining an in memory collection with data from the db). I wonder if I .ToList() both sets of data and join them if the join order still has any impact....

Comment: If i wanted to join 30 objects with another 30, I'd just load them and process client side for convenience. Doing the same on thousands is unacceptable. It's all about data volume.
Also, use **SQL Profiler** to determine how your queries work. Try it on your working version and see what's really happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, great idea.  Also I tested and in my case, the join order becomes irrelevant if I'm operating on two in memory objects created from .ToList()